# Are there any libraries for android that can provide me something simmilar to the algebra capabilities of octave/scipy (fsolve)?

Tags: java, android, matlab, octave, nonlinear-optimization

I am making an android application where I would like to use a few things that are in GNU Octave or Scipy.  The specific things I want to use are: **fsolve** and **fzero**.  fsolve finds a root (zero) of a system of nonlinear equations.  fzero finds the root of a nonlinear function.  These are two really useful optimization functions for me, but I am having a hard time finding an alternative for android.  I have seen posts about using the octave environment through java, but that adds everything in octave which is 90mb added onto my application.  Scipy also has this capability but I havent seen a way to interface this python package through an android application.

Is there anything I can use that ONLY has these optimization methods, so it won't bulk up my android application?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: I'm not super experienced in Android, but I would assume it's quite straightforward to add Java lirbraries to your App? If so [jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) is a linear albegra library which I've used in the past, and I'm sure can replace `fsolve`. For non-linear solver you could probably find a Java library by googling.